# lineLimit in View does not work in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

The text inside my chatbubbles won't break in new line.

Here's the "chatbubble" extracted in an own view

```
struct chatPartnerBubble: View {
    var textMsg: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Text(textMsg)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .padding(10)
                        .lineLimit(nil)
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.leading)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the ChatView

```
ScrollView {
            VStack {
                chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text")
                chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text")
                chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text")
                chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text")
                chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text")
                chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text")
            }
        }
```

But if the textMsg is longer, it just dots..., and does not break into new line

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me... try setting the text to a fixed width with `.frame`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I don't want it to be a fixed width either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired functionality by choosing List over Scrollview. If we consider scalability factor in our chatting app then List is far better than Scrollview. Because views can be easily reusable in List.

```
struct chatPartnerBubble: View {
    var textMsg: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(textMsg)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(10)
            .lineLimit(nil)
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(12)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text1 111111111 1 11111111 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1  111111111111")
            chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text2 22222  222222222 2222222222222 222 2 2 2 22 2 222222")
            chatPartnerBubble(textMsg: "text3 333333 3 333 333 3 3 3 3 33333333 3 33333333 3333333")
        }
        .padding(.top)
        .onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
        }
        .onDisappear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .gray
        }
    }
}
```

In case we have more than one table view in our app, so OnAppear and onDisappear blocks are used to hide/show seperator only for above message table view.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to work fine for me, I'm using Xcode 11.2 Beta 2, so the Xcode version might be the problem. I remember I had a similar problem before and the solution was `VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0)` maybe it helps

[image]

Comment: I have more than one chatbubble. I edited the code in the OP